# How to ocr a pdf directly in the python code

Tags: python, pdf, ocr

I have a stack of scanned documents as pdf files. Now I want to ocr this files. There are some tools which do this, but I can't use them in my python code. I don't want to install one of this tools and run a command.

I want to make something like this:

```
 import ocrmypdf
 ocrmypdf(INPUTFILE, OUTPUTFILE)
```

I found this tools: But all not callable as a python function.

•  ocrmypdf

•  pdf2pdfocr

•  pdfsandwich

•  pypdfocr

•  pdfbeads

Comment: Google says... https://medium.com/@winston.smith.spb/python-ocr-for-pdf-or-compare-textract-pytesseract-and-pyocr-acb19122f38c

Comment: and https://pythontips.com/2016/02/25/ocr-on-pdf-files-using-python/

Comment: You can use the examples and implement them into python functions

Comment: well, it's an upcomming feature for ocrmypfd https://github.com/jbarlow83/OCRmyPDF/pull/373 But I don't now how to use it